# How to validate whether the given input exists in json array or not?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is my data

every time user enters code it should be unique, if there is exists value it should show as error like branch code is exists.

```
 branches: [
          {
            code: "test",
            name: "test",
            email: "test",
            website: "test.com",
            phone: "test",
            address: {
              street: "test",
              city: "test",
              township: "test",
              state: "test",
              zip_code: "test",
              country: "test",
            },
            google_maps_url: "test.com",
          },
        ],
```

this is my code ignore company_details for now i didnt post full data, this is more complex where i cannot display error for particular index field. the index come as parameter to the function on v-on blur.

```
 for(var i=0; i < this.company_details.branches.length; i++){
        if( this.company_details.branches[i].code == this.company_details.branches[index].code){
          count +=1;
        }

        if (count==2){
          this.BranchCodeArray[index].exists = true;
        }
        else{
          this.BranchCodeArray[index].exists = false;
        }
```

Comment: What did you try yourself? Code you add the code you already have at the moment

Comment: I have updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to take some input and see if the input exists in the code field?

You can use filter to get the number of items that the input matches, if the length of the resulting array is > 0, the input is not unique.

```
const branches= [
  {
    code: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test',
    website: 'test.com',
    phone: 'test',
    address: {
      street: 'test',
      city: 'test',
      township: 'test',
      state: 'test',
      zip_code: 'test',
      country: 'test'
    },
    google_maps_url: 'test.com'
  }
];

const doesExist = 'code';
const doesNotExist = 'does not exist'

const exists = !!branches.filter((branch) => branch.code === doesExist).length

const notExists = !!branches.filter((branch) => branch.code === doesNotExist).length
```

You could also map over your data to produce a flat array of codes. You can then see if the codes array includes your input data.

```
const branches= [
  {
    code: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test',
    website: 'test.com',
    phone: 'test',
    address: {
      street: 'test',
      city: 'test',
      township: 'test',
      state: 'test',
      zip_code: 'test',
      country: 'test'
    },
    google_maps_url: 'test.com'
  }
];

const doesExist = 'code';
const doesNotExist = 'does not exist'

const codes = branches.map((branch) => branch.code);

if(codes.includes(doesExist)){
  // Your error logic
}

codes.includes(doesNotExist)
```

Comment: the attribute "code" is like to store only unique values , if the entered code value is already exists i should display error to the user. like there is already a data as "test" ,so when user enters onother array with same value as "test" , i should somehow  show the error message.

Comment: @NikilJ that's what my solution does?

Comment: how can i pass input value  here?@tom
basically i should pass input value to this function as parameter

Comment: if(codes.includes('test')){
  // Your error logic
  alert("hello world");
}   // i have tried this but when the value is entered in branches the "test" is already there , any solution so if it has 2 test so i can display error.